# AudioQueue ate my buffer (first 15 milliseconds of it)

Tags: iphone, c, audio, core-audio

I am generating audio programmatically. I hear gaps of silence between my buffers. When I hook my phone to a scope, I see that the first few samples of each buffer are missing, and in their place is silence. The length of this silence varies from almost nothing to as much as 20 ms.

My first thought is that my original callback function takes too much time. I replace it with the shortest one possible--it re-renqueues the same buffer over and over. I observe the same behavior.

```
AudioQueueRef aq;
AudioQueueBufferRef aq_buffer;
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;

void aq_callback (void *aqData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer) {
    OSStatus s = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(aq, aq_buffer, 0, NULL);
}

void aq_init(void) {
    OSStatus s;

    asbd.mSampleRate = AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_S;
    asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    asbd.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked; 
    asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 1;
    asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1; 
    asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 1;
    asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 8;
    asbd.mReserved = 0;


    int PPM_PACKETS_PER_SECOND = 50;
    // one buffer is as long as one PPM frame
    int BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES = asbd.mSampleRate/PPM_PACKETS_PER_SECOND*asbd.mBytesPerFrame;

    s = AudioQueueNewOutput(&asbd, aq_callback, NULL, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &aq);
    s = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(aq, BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES, &aq_buffer);

    // put samples in the buffer
    buffer_data(my_data, aq_buffer);

    s = AudioQueueStart(aq, NULL);
    s = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(aq, aq_buffer, 0, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the iPhone audio APIs but it appears to be similar to other ones where generally you would queue up  more than one buffer, This way when the system is finished processing the first buffer, it can immediately start processing the next buffer (since it's already been queued up) while the completion callback on the 1st buffer is being executed.

Something like:

```
AudioQueueRef aq;
AudioQueueBufferRef aq_buffer[2];
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;

void aq_callback (void *aqData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer) {
    // note that the callback tells us which buffer has been completed, so all
    //  we have to do is queue it back up
    OSStatus s = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(aq, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}

void aq_init(void) {
    OSStatus s;

    asbd.mSampleRate = AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_S;
    asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    asbd.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked; 
    asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 1;
    asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1; 
    asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 1;
    asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 8;
    asbd.mReserved = 0;


    int PPM_PACKETS_PER_SECOND = 50;
    // one buffer is as long as one PPM frame
    int BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES = asbd.mSampleRate/PPM_PACKETS_PER_SECOND*asbd.mBytesPerFrame;

    s = AudioQueueNewOutput(&asbd, aq_callback, NULL, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &aq);
    s = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(aq, BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES, &aq_buffer[0]);
    s = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(aq, BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES, &aq_buffer[1]);

    // put samples in the buffer - fill both buffers
    buffer_data(my_data, aq_buffer[0]);
    buffer_data(my_data, aq_buffer[1]);

    s = AudioQueueStart(aq, NULL);
    s = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(aq, aq_buffer[0], 0, NULL);
    s = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(aq, aq_buffer[1], 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I can enqueue more than one buffer in init()--this important fact had eluded me. Implementing this suggestion along with changes to the callback improves my situation, but does not resolve it. I still miss the first few ms of some buffers. Now this happens only every 7 or 8 packets, and I miss fewer samples, but it's still noticeable.

Comment: In the simple example it doesn't seem like this should matter, but just in case: does having more than 2 buffers help  (in case you haven't tried it)?  Also, are you sure that `buffer_data()` is filling a buffer with a full 1/50th of a second worth of packets?  What's the value of  `AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_S`?

Comment: Thank you for your continuing support. I stop losing samples if I use 3 buffers instead of 2. This looks like so much magic... the kind of magic I'm uncomfortable with because I can't explain it. I wonder if there is some kind of double-buffering going on. I have previously tried to play with the size of my buffers, making them as long as 1 second (`PPM_PACKETS_PER_SECOND = 1`). With 2 long buffers I still lose samples. With 3 short buffers I get back everything I put in.

Comment: For completeness, the answers to your other questions: I pad the ends of my buffers with well-defined values up to their lengths (buffer_data examines `AudioQueueBuffer.mAudioDataBytesCapacity`) and `AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_S` is `#define`'d to 44100.